# How do I find all installed packages that depend on a given package in NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a npm package that i want to update.  I can update my package.json, but I don't want to break something.  Is there a way to list all of the installed packages that depend on it?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You're looking for https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

For example, to see which packages depend on `contextify` you can run:

```
npm ls contextify
app-name@0.0.1 /home/zorbash/some-project
└─┬ d3@3.3.6
  └─┬ jsdom@0.5.7
    └── contextify@0.1.15
```

Comment: What if I want to see which packages depend on `contextify` when the latter is not installed?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working... i'm my case i have several packages (A, X, Y, Z) which depend on A, which depends on B, which depends on C, which depends on D, which depends on E.  When I rm `npm ls E` it only shows me one of the top-level modules which depends on A.  I'm not sure this is technically correct since X, Y, and Z also depend on it. If it doesn't show X, Y, and Z, what else isn't it showing?

Comment: @modsoussi : see my answer

Comment: `yarn list` for those other people.

Answer (score 20):

You may also find `npm explain <package-name>` useful as it [explains](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/explain) why that package is installed, what depends on it, etc.

e.g. to understand why we have node-sass installed...

```
$ npm explain node-sass
node-sass@4.14.1 dev
node_modules/node-sass
  node-sass@"^4.8.3" from gulp-sass@4.1.1
  node_modules/gulp-sass
    dev gulp-sass@"^4.1.1" from the root project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-dependents to find dependents that are not installed.

**Update**: I see the package is broken, but it still may be a good starting point where the author points out a place where it may be breaking: https://github.com/davidmarkclements/npm-dependents/issues/5#issuecomment-451926479

In the meantime, you may want to just use the "Dependents" tab on the individual npm project pages.